# MySQL query optimisation, big table, using temporary filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I need your help optimizing a query. One table is a log table which has millions of entries and I try to break my query to < 1s. My query should give an overall overview and should be quick therefore. I'm sure I could make multiple simple queries over the list with help of a script. But what a script can do, can mysql I think - I hope at least. And maybe not all parts are best used, but I'm stuck in a query which makes a temporary table and filesort (which I found out is really bad). As reading around I found out to use some neat and well placed indexes but now I'm stuck in a specific point.

Let me show you my final query with its results:

```
SELECT
    ps.SERVER_ID,
    ps.FULLNAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pml.ID_TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'amount_warning',
    SUM(CASE WHEN pml.ID_TYPE = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'amount_error',
    SUM(CASE WHEN pml.ID_TYPE = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'amount_alert',
    SUM(CASE WHEN pml.ID_TYPE = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'amount_critical'
FROM
    PAR_SERVER ps
INNER JOIN
    PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG pml ON ps.SERVER_ID = pml.SERVER_ID
WHERE
    pml.CREATED_DATE > date_sub( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY )
GROUP BY
    ps.SERVER_ID;
```

Here is what I get:

```
mysql> [thequeryabove]
[...]
59 rows in set (11.69 sec)

mysql> explain [thequeryabove]
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pml   | ALL    | SERVER_ID,SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                      | 4014447 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY | 4       | database.pml.SERVER_ID |       1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's my current table setup:

```
mysql> describe PAR_SERVER;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SERVER_ID      | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FULLNAME       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SHORTNAME      | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from PAR_SERVER;
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| PAR_SERVER |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | SERVER_ID   | A         |         142 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_SERVER |          1 | shortname |            1 | SHORTNAME   | A         |         142 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from PAR_SERVER;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      142 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ID_TYPE      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ID_SERVICE   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SERVER_ID    | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| MESSAGE      | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CREATED_DATE | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG;
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | ID          | A         |     3998188 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          1 | ID_TYPE           |            1 | ID_TYPE     | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          1 | ID_SERVICE        |            1 | ID_SERVICE  | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          1 | SERVER_ID         |            1 | SERVER_ID   | A         |          66 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          1 | SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE |            1 | SERVER_ID   | A         |          66 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG |          1 | SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE |            2 | ID_TYPE     | A         |         258 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3998386 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are time results breaking my query step by step down. I may going step by step up after fixing each part taking so long. But for now only the query with runtime of 2.30 sec is currently interesting for this question.

```
mysql> SELECT ps.SERVER_ID, ps.FULLNAME FROM PAR_SERVER ps INNER JOIN PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG pml ON ps.SERVER_ID = pml.SERVER_ID WHERE pml.CREATED_DATE > date_sub( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) GROUP BY ps.SERVER_ID;
[...]
59 rows in set (6.41 sec)

mysql> explain [thequeryabove]
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pml   | ALL    | SERVER_ID,SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                      | 4014788 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY | 4       | database.pml.SERVER_ID |       1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ps.SERVER_ID, ps.FULLNAME FROM PAR_SERVER ps INNER JOIN PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG pml ON ps.SERVER_ID = pml.SERVER_ID GROUP BY ps.SERVER_ID;
[...]
59 rows in set (2.30 sec)

mysql> explain [thequeryabove]
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys               | key       | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pml   | index  | SERVER_ID,SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE | SERVER_ID | 4       | NULL                      | 4015694 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY   | 4       | database.pml.SERVER_ID |       1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT pml.SERVER_ID FROM PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG pml GROUP BY pml.SERVER_ID;
[...]
65 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain [thequeryabove]
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pml   | range | NULL          | SERVER_ID | 4       | NULL |   67 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was able to improve the query a lot by defining an index for (SERVER_ID, ID_TYPE) as my following example query confirms:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) 'count_warnings' FROM PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG pml WHERE pml.SERVER_ID = 191 AND pml.ID_TYPE = 3 GROUP BY pml.SERVER_ID;
[...]
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain [thequeryabove]
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pml   | ref  | ID_TYPE,SERVER_ID,SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE | SERVER_ID-ID_TYPE | 8       | const,const | 10254 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm stuck now in the most broked down query with a long execution time of 2.30 sec. I don't know how to use indexes for such a query not having any where clause.

Comment: A `Using filesort` is not necessarily "really bad"; but for large sets, the sort operation can have a significant impact on performance. Sometimes, it's possible for MySQL to avoid a sort operation when a suitable index is available. Access plans that can make use of covering indexes (`Using index`) generally give better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will definitely benefit the most from adding composite index on PAR_MONITORINGv2_LOG(CREATED_DATE, SERVER_ID,ID_TYPE). However, I suggest even simple index on `CREATED_DATE` will improve performance a lot.